# How to collapse dataframe rows if entry is the same?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in R that has repeated entries in column `a`:

```
a <- c("cat", "dog", "cat", "dog")
b <- c("siamese", "chow", "burmese", "husky")
dataframe <- data.frame(a,b)

   a       b
1 cat siamese
2 dog    chow
3 cat burmese
4 dog   husky
```

How do I collapse entries where a is repeated multiple times?  For example, to end up with a dataframe like this:

```
   a       b
1 cat siamese; burmese
2 dog    chow; husky
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `aggregate` with `paste` setting `collapse = "; "`

```
aggregate(b ~ a, dataframe, paste, collapse = "; ")
#    a                b
#1 cat siamese; burmese
#2 dog      chow; husky
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do :

```r
dataframe %>% 
  group_by(a) %>%
  summarize(b = paste(b, collapse = ", "))
```

Comment: Error in FUN(X, ...) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default.  Note: I fixed the above error by changing spelling of summarize to summarise